# RangeError: Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0. .1: 5 flutter_tag_x itembulder error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<String> added = [ ];

child: Tags(        
      itemCount: _newArrivalsItems.length, //length=32
       itemBuilder: (index) {
         print(index);
         final obj = _newArrivalsItems[index];
         if (added.contains(obj.iGRPCODE)) {
           return Container();
         }
         added.add(obj.iGRPCODE);
         return ItemTags(
           index: index,
           title: obj.iGRPDESC,

           active: true,
           removeButton: ItemTagsRemoveButton(
             onRemoved: () {
               // Remove the item from the data source.
               setState(() {
                 // required
                 _selectedNewArrivalsItemCodes.remove(obj.iGRPCODE);
                 setState(() {});
               });
               //required
               return true;
             },
           ),
```

the length = 32,  when I debug it the itembuilder checked the items upto index=29...when it reach the 30(index) the exception comes from growable_arrays.dart file and it says 'RangeError:  Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0. .1: 5'...
How to fix this error?

Comment: Is `obj.iGRPCODE` an int?

Comment: no..it is a string

Comment: The error indicates you are trying to access something at index 5 of something that only has 2 objects. To me it doesn't seem to correspond to anything in the code that you've shown..